# Numpy Attributes and Methods

Tags: python, numpy, methods, jupyter-notebook, attributes

I need help fixing the errors in my code. Numpy attributes and methods. I added the error I am getting at the end of each code line using asterisk sign.

```
a = np.arrange(10,dtype ='int16')
v = a.view('int32')
print(v)
```

*module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arrange'

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((1,2,3), dtype = geek.complex128)
a = arr.nbytes
print(a)
```

*name 'geek' is not defined

```
import numpy as np
array = np.arrange(15).reshape(3,5)
print ("array : ", array.flat[2:6])
```

*module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arrange'

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array({[0,1],[2,3]],dtype=np.int32)
print(x.ctypes.data)
```

*closing parenthesis ']' does not match opening parenthesis '{', after i fixed the parentheseis the error was "unshapable list"

```
import numpy as np
x = np.dtype('12')
g = x.base
print(g)
```

*data type "" not understood

```
array = np.arrange(10).respace(5,2)
a = np.compress([0,1],array,axis=0)
print(a)
```

*module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arrange'

```
arr = np.arrange(5)
repetitions = 2
a = np.repeat(arr,repetitions)
print(a)
```

*module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arrange'

```
n= 10
m= 20
print(sum(10,20))
```

*'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score -1):

The function is `np.arange`.  READ the docs!

What is `geek`?

Why do you think `np.dtype('12')` would work?  Show the docs that support that.

```
({[0,1],[2,3]],dtype=np.int32)
```

the balance of {([ is obviously wrong.  You don't show the correction, so I can't comment on the following error.

Python function tales an iterable (eg a list) as argument.  You gave it 2 numbers.  Again read your docs.